# Can you include GwtBootstrap3 in an existing GWT project

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a project that has taken me 2 years, in my spare time, to develop (I am not a developer by trade) and has over 50 views. I have been told that to produce a better user experience and speed up my development I should use GwtBootstrap3. At this time I do not have time to rewrite the whole project so is it possible to include GwtBootstrap3 in the existing project, build new views using GwtBootstrap3 and slowly converting existing views to GwtBootstrap3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking the answer is Yes, follow [setup guide](http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#setup)  of gwtbootstrap3. But, gwtbootstrap3 inject few default css in application on load which might can affect few of your current views. Hope you are following some kind of mvp patterns, if not first start use of it and then go for modifying existing views.